# Resolving to a different main file per directory

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a `components` directory which hosts several sub folders with actual components. Each folder has main file named as the name of folder plus extension. Then I have to create `index.js` file containing something like `export default from './MyComponent';`.

So my question is if there is a way in Webpack to get rid of those `index.js` files and instead dynamically point to component file itself. Perhaps I could write some plugin, I haven't looked much into a plugin system yet. Just wondering if it's even possible to change fundamentals like this.

Comment: you can also add `package.json` in folder `MyComponent` pointing to your main file `"main": "./MyComponent.js"`.

Comment: If you are still going to write some plugin, try this first https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-directory-name-as-main

Comment: @AndreyEtumyan Great - this plugin will do the trick. But probably you will lose IDE support for path to module :(

Comment: @AndreyEtumyan Thanks, I tried it, but it is also producing strange issue with node_modules. There is a similar issue to it, but author doesn't seem to maintain module anymore.

Comment: Also I found out that it doesn't work well with `eslint-import-resolver-webpack`. It would require some additional effort to make that working correctly.